# Error 'An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia' appears to already be loaded in your kernel' when trying to get GPU support in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, nvidia

I'm getting the following error when trying to apply a publicly available AWS DL AMI to a EMR cluster (emr-6.2.0, spark 3.0.1)

From the puppet.log file from the app-phase:

```
ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia' appears to already be loaded in your kernel. This may be because it is in use (for example, by an X server, a CUDA program, or the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon), but this may also happen if your kernel was configured without support for module unloading. Please be sure to exit any programs that may be using the GPU(s) before attempting to upgrade your driver. If no GPU-based programs are running, you know that your kernel supports module unloading, and you still receive this message, then an error may have occured that has corrupted an NVIDIA kernel module's usage count, for which the simplest remedy is to reboot your computer.
```

Linux version within the cluster is

```
Linux ip-10-14-1-68 4.14.26-46.32.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 30 22:29:54 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

DLAMI = ami-058964fc61ad6c7c8
Tensorflow version = 2.4.1

Is there any fix or workaround to this issue?  Some clean way to remove Nvidia perhaps and allow it to be reinstalled or kill some processes holding onto it? or something else.

Answer (score 3):

In case you try to install a new version of nvidia's driver, you want to make sure no other processes use the older driver version.

You can find those processes with:

```sh
sudo lsof /dev/nvidia*
```

Then, kill the processes by the corresponding `PID` with `kill -9 PID`.

Comment: Thanks, @OmriKaduri.
We have tried with something very similar.

Basically, in a bootstrap action:

`ps -ef | grep [n]vidia | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9`

However, past that command:

`Shutting down nvidia processes...`
`listing nvidia procs after the proc kill attempt:`
`root      6208     2  0 15:02 ?        00:00:00 [irq/109-nvidia]`
`root      6209     2  0 15:02 ?        00:00:00 [nvidia]`


These processes are not easily killable. Gotta figure out how to cleanly shut those down.